# Laravel - how to add variable type to parameter of controller method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

I have a controller method that has a parameter. I need to add a type to it:

```
public function deleteIndex(int $user_id)
    {
        return DB::try(function () use ($user_id) {
            if (empty($user_id)) {
                return error(trans('user.invalid_data_recheck'));
            }

            $user = User::find($user_id);

            if (empty($user)) {
                return error(trans('user.invalid_user'));
            }

            if (!$user->delete()) {
                return error(trans('user.could_not_delete_user'));
            }

            return success();
        });
    }
```

The route looks like this:

```
AdvancedRoute::controllers([
    'users'       => 'API\UserAPIController'
]);
```

From the JS the parameter is being sent like this: `'/users/{user_id}'`

The issue I have is, when I add the parameter type: "int" in the controller method, the endpoint is no longer reached, if I remove "int" everything works fine. But I need that for an openapi library that I use. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: as you have defined parameter int, your parameter should also be int. You are passing integer value to the route. But javascript everytime send and accept value as text. try by parseInt() from js end

Comment: if this does not work then try typecasting like 
$userid = (int)$userid;

Comment: @ArifulIslam you are right, from js it comes as string, and not even parseInt is able to change that. Sadly I need the type specified next to the parameter not in the body of the function, so I cannot do $userid = (int)$userid;